# how to send emails from amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

Recently I have switched my hosting from bluehost to amazon ec2. I need to know, how my application would be able to send the emails from amazon ec2? Do I need to install any smtp server on my instance or I have to configure amazon SES? Please help.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Noone gets to send email directly out of EC2 without signing up to [SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/) and working within its constraints.  Good grief, AWS would just be one enormous and thoroughly blackholed spam factory without SES in place.

Might also be worth looking at whether AWS's [SNS](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/) might be a better solution for whatever you're trying to do.

**Update:** it is possible to send [email directly from AWS](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=317525), but you'll want to let AWS know by filling in a form so that they can whitelist the IP.

**Update:** More up to date treatment of this topic in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829141/send-emails-from-aws-ec2-instance-ses-mandatory?rq=1).

Comment: You don't *have* to use SES. You could use SendGrid or Mandrill for free, or any other external SMTP server.

Comment: as the above comment suggested, the answer is misleading.

Comment: @DanGrossman, Mandrill seems to have a reputation for delivering spam...

Comment: @Pacerier, Mandrill is MailChimp, perhaps the largest marketing mailer worldwide with over 6 million businesses using them to send over 70 billion e-mails. They have stronger relationships with ISPs than any other company. They also do not permit any mail be sent to any recipient that hasn't opted-in. They do not have a reputation for delivering spam.

Comment: @DanGrossman, Where'd you get those stats from?

Comment: @Pacerier http://mailchimp.com/2013/#emails-sent

Comment: This answer is incorrect. It is possible to send emails from an EC2 instance. You must fill in an online form with Amazon to remove the sending restrictions and set up the reverse DNS.

Comment: Those mechanisms weren't in place when I answered this in 2012; it was SES or nothing (not counting 3rd party providers).  Not sure what etiquette is here; if it was more on topic I'd be inclined to update the answer (as could anyone with edit privs), but it seems pointless for a closed question.

Comment: @timday As passing here from a google search for how to send mail from EC2 (1 year later :p), I do think an update would be great. Your answer is perfectly valid but could be more helpful including the comments about 3rd party providers and Luke comment (which unfortunately didn't provide any link to back up this point). Just my 2cts obviously and not a begging for update in any way.

Comment: If the emails you are sending are transactional -- ie few, related to transactions, and important -- you probably do want to use SES rather than using ec2, as the ec2 and Elastic IP addresses generally have lower email reputations than SES IP addresses.

This also allows you to create a "trusted" email pathway out of your server - anything infecting the server will be sending email from the server IP and thus will be less likely to be trusted (as well as clearly not from SES).  SES bounces can be harder to track though.