# Send emails from AWS EC2 instance (SES mandatory?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ses

I write this post just to see if I can get some clarifications regarding email sending concepts in an AWS EC2 instance.

This is related with this other post [Rails does not send emails on AWS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23814906/rails-does-not-send-emails-on-aws/23817424?noredirect=1#23817424)

I´m developing a Rails application that sends emails to customers (such as confirmation or information emails).

I dont know exactly which email service is using Rails. I didn´t install any particular gem. But the emails are been sent perfectly in development environment (Ubuntu).

When I deploy to my production environment (AWS EC2 instance). This functionality is not working. You can see the error details in the post I provided above. The error is related with some `smtp connection refused`.

So, I have read some other posts but Im confused. Is it mandatory to use the AWS SES service in order to send emails from EC2 instance? Or it is just a problem related to security credentials (maybe I just need to open the smtp 25 port). Do I need to install any email client or server?

Comment: can you post the code which sends mail in production?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sending emails from EC2 instances is limited by Amazon and strictly throttled at network level.  This is to prevent spamming and other abuses.

If you have a large amount of emails to send to your customers, the recommended way is to use [Amazon Simple Email Service](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/).  With Amazon SES, you can send transactional email, marketing messages, or any other type of high-quality content and you only pay for what you use.

If you really need to send emails from an EC2 instance, you must use an Elastic IP Adress and ask Amazon's support to remove limitations on SMTP traffic from that EIP.
The form to contact us is available at https://portal.aws.amazon.com/gp/aws/html-forms-controller/contactus/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request (authentication is required)

Seb

Comment: I don´t have a very large amount of emails to send to my customers,neither marketing campaign emails, but my application is a booking application, so, our mails are more transactional like, booking confirmation emails with dates, registration emails, and so on. Probably in the future I need marketing emails with SES, but so far, Im not sure that we need it. I mean, Im still not sure if I can send emails from my EC2 instances without SES. As far as I undestand you can request it to AWS guys? Do they evaluate if they will allow to send the emails from EC2?

Comment: Your use case is one of the typical use case for SES - confirmation emails are possibly large volumes for which SES has been designed.

Comment: If you really want to send emails from EC2, please follow the link I gave and fill-in the form to ask AWS Support to remove the email limit for your EIP

Answer (score 2):

As sebasto wrote, sending emails is limited.

See the question "Are there any limitations in sending email from EC2 instances?: in the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/)

You will need to check to see if you have SMTP installed.

Try this code:

```
[ec2-user@ip ~]$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'net/smtp'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Net::SMTP.start('localhost') do |smtp|
irb(main):003:1* smtp.send_message 'test from ruby', 'your-email', 'your-email'
irb(main):004:1> end
```

For my gmail account, this worked.

Comment: I think you meant 'your-email', 'your-email' there, right?

Comment: Perfect. Mine (@gmail) also working. It is definitely a good alternative to Amazon SES.