# ec2 node.js server not sending email - any ideas?

Tags: node.js, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a website that I'm getting back up after a year+ of being down. I haven't made any code changes, and I've got the site back up and everything is working as before except for the site/app sending email.

It's an ubuntu node.js server. It's hosted on Amazon and I had to create another instance and repoint the dns, etc. An example code snippet that used to work but now doesn't:

```
var emailServer  = email.server.connect({user:"<my gmail>",password:"<mypw>",host:"smtp.gmail.com",ssl:true});
emailServer.send({
          text:    "Your username is: " + userName + ".", 
          to:      emailAddress,
          subject: "Activate Your a2zCribbage Account",
          attachment: [...]
        }, function(err, message) { if (err) console.log(err); });
```

When I first tried to send email the gmail account I use got a message "sign-in attempt prevented" Someone just tried to sign in to your Google Account <account> from an app that doesn't meet modern security standards.

I followed what Google said and changed the security to allow apps, but still nothing gets sent.

What am I missing? What other things can I try? Do ec2 severs not just allow email to be sent by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gmail is not a platform for sending automated email.](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en) Just because you *can* doesn't mean it's designed for doing so.

[AWS EC2 instances are also problematic for sending email](http://shlomoswidler.com/2009/07/sending-email-from-ec2.html); the ports may be blocked or [throttled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23829141/send-emails-from-aws-ec2-instance-ses-mandatory), you are certainly getting higher spam scores for doing so.

The canonical solution is to use [AWS SES](https://aws.amazon.com/ses/). [Here's sample code](https://timstermatic.github.io/blog/2013/08/14/sending-emails-with-node-dot-js-and-amazon-ses/) and [here's the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html). There's also [a simple third-party library](https://github.com/aheckmann/node-ses).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm still working through the SES implementation and haven't gotten it completely working yet (hoping to get some time this evening) which is why I haven't accepted the answer just yet, but I will once I do.

Comment: I can't get this to work. I verified the domain and copied all the syntax from the sample code and the code runs without error and it simply doesn't send email that is delivered. I guess I will accept this answer and post another question about the specific error I am getting now.